# Ruby/Rails - Nested blocks without hitting the DB everytime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not exactly sure how to look this up, but I'm not finding the solution anywhere. I want to assign an array of users an array of websites. Like so:

```
users = User.all
sites = Site.all

users.each do |user|
  sites.each do |site|
     user.websites << site
  end
end
```

Obviously, this does not work because I'm missing something about block scope. However, this works:

```
users.each do |user|
  Site.all.each do |site|
    user.websites << site
  end
end
```

But I'm trying to eliminate the extra calls to the DB (Site.all.each ...) and learn something about Ruby in the process. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why does the first way not work, what is the error message?

Comment: First one looks good. How is it failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your User model is in a has many relationship with Websites (classname Sites), then you can just do

```
users = User.all
sites = Site.all

users.each do |user|
  user.websites = sites
end
```

Edit: For Harpastum:

If user.websites contains items not in Site.all that you don't want over written the following works.

```
users = User.all
sites = Site.all

users.each do |user|
  user.websites << sites
end
```

Comment: I'm new to rails, but wouldn't that set the value of user.websites to just the new array? i.e. Wouldn't any previous records in user.websites get overwritten?

Comment: Yes. But, it wouldn't matter given the assumption of a has_many relationship. There could be no items in websites that don't exist in Site.all

Comment: Thanks once again, EmFi. You're a big help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the first attempt wouldn't work, but I also don't really understand why you'd append each site separately. Wouldn't this work?

```
users = User.all
sites = Site.all

users.each do |user|
    user.websites.concat(sites)
end
```

[ruby-doc link to concat](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002166)

If they're actually hashes (although you say they're arrays), the method you're looking for is [merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002880)